# MYSQL Add column value based upon id

Tags: mysql

I have two table,

order

```
product_id | name     | quantity
-----------------------------
136        | product1 | 10
137        | product2 | 18
138        | product3 | 5
136        | product1 | 25
136        | product1 | 35
```

product

```
id       | product_id | quantity
-----------------------------
1        | 136        | 100
2        | 137        | 90
3        | 138        | 145
4        | 139        | 100
```

I want the result for remaining quantity, that is add the quantity based upon product_id in oreder table. This answer subtract from product table based upon product_id.

For example, i assume product_id is 136. in oeder table there is three column present. 
To add the quantity (i.e)10+25+35=70.

This value subtracted from quantity of product table. In product table the quantity of product_id is 100.
so result is 100-70=30.
I want output is 30.
This will follow all other product_id also.

mysql is,

`$sql = "SELECT op.name,  o.quantity-SUM(DISTINCT op.quantity)  AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order op LEFT JOIN`" . DB_PREFIX . "product`o ON (op.product_id = o.product_id)";`

Answer (score 1):

Do the aggregation *before* joining:

```
select p.*, (p.quantity - coalesce(q, 0)) as q_remaining
from product p left join
     (select product_id, sum(quantity) as q
      from `order`
      group by product_id
     ) o
     on o.product_id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.productid,a.quantity-b.orders
from product b
left join (select product_id,sum(quantity) as orders
            from   order
            group by product_id) b on a.product_id=b.product_id
```

Comment: the subquery collect the total orders quantity